# Как устроена асинхронность (async/await) в Dart?

Tags: асинхронность, async-await, dart

И так, я изучаю Dart и добрался до темы `async/await`, но не понимаю как она устроена. Далеко ходить не буду, а сразу пример:

```
void main() {
  print("${DateTime.now()} main");
  func();
  func3();
}

func() async {
  var result = await func2();
  print("${DateTime.now()} $result");
}

Future<String> func2() async {
  // await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000000000; ++i) {}
  return "func2";
}

func3() {
  print("${DateTime.now()} func3");
}
```

Результат выполнения данного кода будет следующим:

```
2024-02-20 11:20:07.035210 main
2024-02-20 11:20:09.484226 func3
2024-02-20 11:20:09.485226 func2
```

**Вопрос:** почему лог `func3` выводится одновременно с `func2`? Я так понимаю, это из-за того, что функция считается асинхронной, если в ней есть `await` или возврат `Future`, потому что если я уберу комментарий со строки `await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);` (которая по сути бесполезна) или сделаю нечто такое:

```
Future<String> func2() async {
  return Future<String>(() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000000; ++i) {}
    return "func2";
  });
}
```

, то посмотрите как меняется вывод:

```
2024-02-20 11:23:30.396179 main
2024-02-20 11:23:30.400179 func3
2024-02-20 11:23:32.910888 func2
```

Теперь, лог `func3` не выводится вместе с `func2` — это я и понимаю под асинхронностью. Выполнение программы в `main()` идёт дальше, а не останавливается на `func()`. Почему для этого обязательно наличие `await` и использования `Future` в любом виде? Почему как только я добавляю `Future`, то асинхронность сразу же работает? Также кстати и с `Stream`. Компилятор вообще никак не реагирует на то, что я пометил функцию как `async`?

*P.S. Вот допустим пример кода на Java на котором я делаю практически тоже самое — запускаю отдельный поток и иду дальше. Фраза "main" будет выведена моментально, а остальной код будет выполнятся параллельно сразу же. То есть, он начнет работу не в момент вызова `future.get()`, а сразу же. От Dart ожидаю тоже самое, но работает как то по-другому... (да, тут код в потоке зависнет из-за переполнения типа)*

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; ++i) {
                i += 1;
            }
            return "Hello";
        });
        System.out.println("main");
        System.out.println(future.get());
    }
```

Comment: _Результат выполнения данного кода будет следующим: программа дождётся пока будет выполнена функция func2() и только затем выполнит func3()_ - в онлайн редакторе всегда выводится `func3` `true`. Почему ты думаешь, что сначала выполняется `func2`?

Comment: Асинхронность и многопоточность - это разные концепции. Асинхронность возможна даже с одним единственным потоком. Поскольку вы из `main` синхронно вызываете асинхронные функции, вообще сложно сказать, как это должно по-нормальному работать. Не знаю ничего про `Dart`, но в других языках `main` тоже должен быть асинхронным, а результат работы вызываемых в нём функций  должен тоже ожидаться через `await`.

Comment: @Grundy потому что я запустил код

Comment: @CrazyElf, не _должен быть асинхронным_, а _может быть асинхронным_. Ничто не мешает запускать асинхронную операцию и не ждать пока она выполнится

Comment: @ulxanxv, что ты увидел при запуске? Вывод в обоих случаях ожидаемый `func3` `true`.

Comment: @Grundy сейчас дополню пост

Comment: Судя по скриншоту - вывод ожидаемый. Что конкретно в нем не устраивает?

Comment: @Grundy вы, наверное, плохо поняли вопрос. Я хочу запустить func() отдельно от основного сценария. То есть на самом деле вывод должен быть вот такой ```2024-02-19 18:18:23.281803
2024-02-19 18:18:23.285802 func3
2024-02-19 18:18:25.735196 true```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151555/discussion-between-grundy-and-ulxanxv).

Comment: Асинхронность и многопоточность путаете не только вы, разработчики java тоже начудили с `CompletableFuture`: метод `supplyAsync` по-умолчанию использует пул потоков, а для запуска задачи в текущем потоке, как делает дарт, придется писать свой исполнитель и самому его дергать. Кроме того, "асинхронные" операции в обоих случаях по неведомым причинам гвоздями прибиты к объектам future, через которые происходит ожидание получение результат операции.

Comment: @CrazyElf многопоточность тоже возможна с одним ядром и одним потоком. у процессора есть прерывания. другой вопрос о производительности такого приложения, но в целом то возможно. windows будет распределять время

Comment: @user7860670 то есть создать какую то свою асинхронность нельзя? Только использование Future или Stream гарантирует асинхронное исполнение? Если этого не будет, то компилятор не обратит внимание на то, что я пометил функцию как `async`? Приводя в пример ту же Java - там это не обязательно. Функция может делать вообще всё что угодно и достаточно просто заюзать API, чтобы вынести данную функцию в параллельное исполнение?

Comment: Почему же нельзя, можно, а вот использование Future или Stream как раз не нужно. Это встроенные в языки механизмы асинхронности почему-то их используют. И опять, не путайте асинхронное исполнение и параллельное. Асинхронность не подразумевает обязательного параллельного выполнения. А параллельность не подразумевает обязательного асинхронного выполнения.

Comment: @user7860670 ну вот буквально в моем примере: если в `async` методе не будет `Future` или `Stream`, то программа исполняется синхронно. Почему ключевое слово `async` игнорируется?

Comment: Асинхронным метод делает не использование `async`, `Future`, `Stream` или еще каких-то встроенных языковых средств, а подход к решению задачи, когда используется некоторый объект, содержащий ее текущее состояние, а действия по ее выполнению можно производить по требованию, произвольно перемежая с другими вычислениями.

Comment: Насколько я могу понять ваши примеры вывода, у вас всегда вывод func3 идет перед выводом из func, т.е. func3 завершается раньше, чем func2, которая текстуально запускается ранее. Следовательно, вы всегда наблюдаете асинхронное выполнение функций.